# How to check the length of an Observable array

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-template, angular2-services

In my Angular 2 component I have an Observable array

```ts
list$: Observable<any[]>;
```

In my Template I have

```html
<div *ngIf="list$.length==0">No records found.</div>

<div *ngIf="list$.length>0">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of list$ | async">item.name</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But list$.length doesn't work with in case of Observable array.

**Update:**

It seems that **(list$ | async)?.length** gives us the length but the below code still doesn't work:

```html
<div>
    Length: {{(list$ | async)?.length}}
    <div *ngIf="(list$ | async)?.length>0">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of (list$ | async)">
                {{item.firstName}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please guide how do I check length of Observable array.

Comment: Reported at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9641

Comment: Your approach here has another major issue: by leveraging the async pipe over and over in your template, you are actually kicking off that many subscriptions to the single Observable. KAMRUL HASAN SHAHED has the right approach above: Use the async pipe once and then provide an alias for the result that you can leverage in child nodes.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

You can use the `| async` pipe:

```html
<div *ngIf="(list$ | async)?.length==0">No records found.</div>
```

**Update - 2021-2-17**

```html
<ul *ngIf="(list$| async) as list; else loading">
   <li *ngFor="let listItem of list">
      {{ listItem.text }}
   </li>
</ul>

<ng-template #loading>
  <p>Shows when no data, waiting for Api</p>
  <loading-component></loading-component>
</ng-template>
```

**Update - Angular Version 6:**

If you are loading up a css Skeleton you can use this. If the array has no items it will display the css template. If there is data then fill out the `ngFor`.

```html
<ul *ngIf="(list$| async)?.length > 0; else loading">
   <li *ngFor="let listItem of list$| async">
      {{ listItem.text }}
   </li>
</ul>

<ng-template #loading>
  <p>Shows when no data, waiting for Api</p>
  <loading-component></loading-component>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I tried that as well but it gives error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"

Comment: Hard to know from the information you provided. Try `<div *ngIf="(list$ | async)?.length==0">No records found.</div>` (added `?`)

Comment: I tried this and it works <div *ngIf="(list$ | async)?.length==0">No records found.</div>

Comment: The additional `?` is required because `list$` is only set *after* Angular2 tries to render the view the first time. `?` prevents the rest of the sub-expression to be evaluated until the part left of `?` becomes `!= null` (Elvis or safe-navigation operator).

Comment: Yes that makes send, but the below code doesn't work:

<div>
    Length: {{(list$ | async)?.length}}
    <div *ngIf="(list$ | async)?.length>0">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of (list$ | async);">
                {{item.firstName}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

Though the list length is printed (i.e. 20) but it doesn't render the list if placed under the ngIf. If I remove ngIf, it start working. Can you please guide?

Comment: Please have a look at http://plnkr.co/edit/5KBEVj5Hhtx0BB5v3vVg?p=preview if you remove <div *ngIf="(todos$ | async)?.length>0"> from todo.component, it will start displaying list.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is there a way to alias (list$ | async) with as then use alias.length?

Comment: @JGFMK Yes, that should work with recemt 4.x.x versions.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Did you mean this? {{ (myArray | customPipe )?.length}} Only the link didn't take - I'll give it a try later - cheers

Comment: @JGFMK sorry https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521254/get-length-of-array-in-ngfor-after-pipes-transformation

Comment: How does it work with the `as` keyword: `<ion-list *ngIf="!query && (uniqueTodayCollected | async) as today">`. Want to check the length so ion-list is hidden if uniqueTodayCollected.length == 0

Comment: Used this to fix: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9641#issuecomment-299167085

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it looks to me, that first `async` pipe resolves data and therefore my next `async` pipe on loop doesn't display anything. Or maybe `*ngIf` creates an additional scope and therefore it is not working. Hard to tell. But while my loop is wrapped inside if, it doesn't display any data. If itself evaluates to `true` correctly.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - in the above code you subscribe to the same resource using async pipe twice - it would be better to use `as` syntax: `<ul *ngIf="(list$| async as list)?.length > 0; else loading">
   <li *ngFor="let listItem of list">
      {{ listItem.text }}
   </li>
</ul>` to store subscription in template variable `list` (pay attention to no dollar sign) and then use this one in the template - thus avoiding multiple subscriptions.

Comment: You are right. `as` wasn't a thing yet back then when I posted the answer and I don't have the time anymore to keep my answers updated.

Comment: will this not create 2 subscriptions? you could wrapp it `<ng-container *ngIf="list$ | async as list">` and then `<ul *ngIf="list.length > 0; else loading">`

Answer (score 42):

A solution for .ts-Files:

```
     this.list.subscribe(result => {console.log(result.length)});
```

Comment: isn't it necessary to immediately unsubscribe afterwards?

Comment: It's better to unsubscribe from observables on `onDestroy` component

Comment: @ThPadelis That depends on the observable's lifespan...

Answer (score 25):

For Angular 4+, try this

```
<div *ngIf="list$ | async;let list">
    Length: {{list.length}}
    <div *ngIf="list.length>0">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of list">
                {{item.firstName}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

While this answer is correct

```
<div *ngIf="(list$ | async)?.length === 0">No records found.</div>
```

Keep in mind that if you are using http client to call backend (in most cases you do) you will get duplicate calls to your API if you have more that one **list$ | async**. This is because each | async pipe will create new subscriber to your list$ observable.

Answer (score 4):

Can be shortened as well:

```
<div *ngIf="!(list$ | async)?.length">No records found.</div>
```

Just use the exclamation mark before the parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me -

```
*ngIf="!photos || photos?.length===0"
```

I am getting my data from httpClient async.

All the other options here didn't work for me which was disappointing. 
Especially the sexy (list$ | async) pipe.

Basa..

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with `Observable<Customer[]>` (initialized in a constructor) saying "object is possibly undefined" when trying to hide container div when arr length is empty
So I had it like this: `<div *ngIf="(similarCustomers$ | async)?.length > 0">`

My co-worker solved it by doing this:

```
<div *ngIf="(similarCustomers$ | async) as similarCustomers">
  <ng-container *ngIf="similarCustomers.length > 0">
```

Answer (score -3):

ionic 4

```
<div *ngIf="(items | async)?.length==0">No records found.</div>
```

it worked when i removed the `$` sign

Comment: `$` sign is used to denote Observable. It has nothing to do with working/logic. Its just a convention followed in Angular.