# I want to get the length/size of my Observable and display it in the template

Tags: angular

I have an Observable in my service and I want to display its size/length as part of my pagination.

```
public document: SomeClass[]

getDocument(): Observable<SomeClass[]> {
       return this._http.get(this.jsonURL)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

<div *ngFor='let resultItem of document; let count=index'></div>

<pagination>{{document.length}}</pagination>
```

This is throwing an error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

How should it be done? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it by putting *ngIf to check if document has value or not since it is an Observable and called Asynchronously. It means that data will come in later.

```
<pagination *ngIf='document'>{{document.length}}</pagination>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `public document: SomeClass[]`

document is not initialized, so there is no object which could have length attribute.

Initialize object, or use other variable in template, and update it.

```
private observableLegth: number = 0
```

and then

```
 observableLength = document.length
```

somewhere in your component class **(when document is defined!)**

Comment: This throws me "Property length does not exist on type 'Observable<someType[]>'." This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40237063/5326490 did worked for me in the .ts file, though you have to take the order of execution into consideration since the code executed inside the .subscribe() callback runs asynchronously.