# Only show div when observable stream is empty

Tags: angular, observable

I'm using a text search feature similar to the [angular2 heros](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) tutorial, but am having trouble hiding a div when user is not searching. I have the following code in my component:

```
searchLocations: Observable<Location[]>;
private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

// ...

ngOnInit(): void {
    // ...
    this.searchLocations = this.searchTerms
        .debounceTime(300)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap(term => term
            ? this.locationSearchService.search(term)
            : Observable.of<Location[]>([]))
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
            return Observable.of<Location[]>([]);
        });
}
```

then within my html, I display the results of a user searching with

```
<div class="results">
    <div *ngFor="let loc of searchLocations | async" class="search-result">
        {{ loc.name }}, {{ loc.adminName1 }}, {{ loc.countryCode }}
    </div>
</div>
```

But with my current code, the `results` div is **always** present. How can I check when an observable stream is empty? I tried `.count()` and `.length()`, but both of these also return observables.... I assume I need to do something like:

```
<div class="results" *ngIf="???">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: Possible due of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057537/how-to-check-length-of-the-an-observable-array

Answer (score 16):

In your ngIf directive, you should also use the async pipe, because this is Observable:

```
  <div class="results" *ngIf="!(searchLocations | async)?.length">
        <div *ngFor="let loc of searchLocations | async" class="search-result">
            {{ loc.name }}, {{ loc.adminName1 }}, {{ loc.countryCode }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add some commentary to your code snippet to help the OP understand how your solution works

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, gives me `error: cannot read property 'length' of null`

Comment: syntactic fructose this works for me and its the ? will handle the null

Comment: I do not recommend two async pipes for the same parameter,
better use <ng-container *ngIf="searchLocations | async as locations"><div *ngif="locations.length"><div *ngFor="let loc of locations">...</div></div></ng-container>