# (Angular2) `*ngfor` doesn't work with filter using pipe from async data

Tags: javascript, angular

I have simple Angular 2 app as below:

**Data structure**

```
class Item {
  name: string,
  status: boolean
}
```

**Template**

```
<ul *ngIf="items">
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

**Component**

```
export class ItemsComponent implement OnInit {

  items: Item[]

  constructor(private itemService: ItemService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getItems();
  }

  private getItems(): void {
    this.itemService.getItems().then(items => this.items = items);
  }

}
```

with asynchronous data receiver `getItems()` of `ItemService` which uses `Promise`.

This app works great. The full item list is shown on the browser.

---

I want to display only the items with status `true`. To do this, I implemented a simple pipe to filter `items` by `status`:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterByStatus'
})
export class FilterByStatusPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(votes: Vote[], status: boolean): Vote[] {
    return votes.filter(vote => vote.status === status);
  }
}
```

and I updated `li` tag in my template as

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items|filterByStatus:true">{{ item.name }}</li>
```

But, this update makes `<ul *ngIf="items">` false so `<li>`s are not computed. (i.e. `items === undefined`)

I don't know why first version works well but updated version does not. And how can I get `items` with `status === true`?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057537/how-to-check-length-of-the-an-observable-array/38057574#38057574

Comment: your code is actually correct and should work as is. How sure are you that `vote.status` is actually filled with a boolean? It also makes no sense that a pipe makes `items` be undefined. Something else is wrong there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Everybody should know:

**DON'T** use `status` for the name of your properties or variables. It would be potentially used in your environment.

See this: [JS reserved keywords list](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

---

**Renaming** solves the problem.