# Length of observable array using 'as' syntax

Tags: angular

`"@angular/core": "^6.1.4"`

Here is my .html:

```
  <div *ngIf="errors$ | async as errors">
    <div class="container alert alert-danger" *ngIf="errors.length > 0">
      <b>{{errors.length}} error(s)</b>
      <ul *ngFor="let error of errors">
        <li>{{error}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My question is: can I reduce it down to a single `*ngIf`?

I have tried the following:

```
(errors$ | async as errors).length > 0
(errors$ | async as errors) && errors.length > 0
```

Both of these gave a template parse error.

I have already looked at [How to check the length of an Observable array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057537/how-to-check-the-length-of-an-observable-array), this question is different because I want to use `as` syntax.

All I want to do is subscribe to the observable with the `as` syntax and only show this div if the length of the array is greater than 0. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this

```
*ngIf="(errors$ | async)?.length > 1 && (errors$ | async)?.length < 5"
```

or

```
*ngIf="(errors$ | async)?.length > 0 && (errors$ | async) as errors">
```

**Update**

there is an issue for this on github. please see [the link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16173). Obviously this behaviour is not yet supported.

Comment: Cool this works, but I want to avoid multiple async pipes on the same object

Comment: I am also thinking that. If I find proper solution I will update my post :)

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your answer nonetheless.

Comment: you may also consider to use share() operator within rxjs library which can help you to eliminate multiple server request using same observable service

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, please consider to upvote and/or accept it as answer. regards

Comment: Accepting this answer as it looks like this is a current feature request on Angular's official GitHub.